# The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, abp

Hi I am using Abp Framework with .net 7 and I have this service that has one to many relationship
in the dto of the entity i have list and when I send rquest from swagger to this sevice i get this error
The instance of entity type 'B' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

This is my model

```
`
public class A: AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
    {
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<B> Bs{ get; set; } = new List<B>();
    }
public class TaxAddressIdentity : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
        public required string Phone { get; set; }
        public required Guid AId { get; set; }
        public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
`
```

And this is my dto

```
`public class CreateUpdateADto: EntityDto<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CreateUpdateBDto> Bs{ get; set; }

}`
```

And this is the service

```
`public interface IAAppService :
    ICrudAppService< 
        ADto, 
        Guid, 
        AGetListInput,
        CreateUpdateADto,
        CreateUpdateADto>
{

}
public class AAppService : CrudAppService<A, ADto, Guid, AGetListInput, CreateUpdateADto, CreateUpdateADto>,
    IAAppService
{
 public async override Task<ADto> CreateAsync(CreateUpdateADto input)
{
     try
        {
            return  await base.CreateAsync(input);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }   
    
}`
```

And this is the mapping i am using in side the file ProjectNameApplicationAutoMapperProfile

```
CreateMap<A, ADto>();
CreateMap<CreateUpdatADto, A>(MemberList.Source);
```

can you give me any hekp please? i try every thing but still git the same error